# Как сделать метод класса callback-функцией?

Tags: callback, glut, классы, c++, opengl

Решил сделать класс GlutApp, чтобы упростить использование glut. И столкнулся с такой проблемой. Я сделал виртуальную функцию в классе GlutApp:

```
class GlutApp
{
    //...
    virtual void Display();
    //...
};
```

А в конструкторе написал следующее:

```
GlutApp::GlutApp(int argc, char **argv)
{
    //...
    glutDisplayFunc(Display);
    //...
}
```

В результате получил ошибку:

```
glutapp.cpp:11:26: error: cannot convert ‘void (GlutApp::*)()’ to ‘void (*)()’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void glutDisplayFunc(void (*)())’
```

И ещё три подобные. Почему так? Как выправить ситуацию? Как сделать метод класса callback-функцией?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589422/using-opengl-glutdisplayfunc-within-class

Comment: Да, придумали приключения на свою голову... Согласен с ссылкой @Котик_хочет_кушать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В большинстве случаев это сделать нельзя. Даже если извратиться и с помощью `reinterpret_cast` конвертировать указатель на функцию-член в указатель на простую функцию, работать она будет неправильно, если обращается к элементам своего класса. На самом деле в качестве одного из параметров скрыто передается указатель на объект (тот самый `this`). Ну а дальше делаете выводы...

Однако, я в одном случае нашел выход: если объект создается в глобальной области видимости. Используется такая система оберток

```
class A {
    int i;
  public:
    A(int i_) : i(i_) {}

    void say() { //функция, которую caller должен в конечном счете вызвать
        cout << "I say: " << i << endl;
    }
};

void caller (void (*f) ()) { //вызыватель 
    f();
}

A a(77);

void wrap () { //обертка, выполняющая роль call-back function
    a.say();
}

int main() {
    caller (wrap); 
}
```

В таком случае нужно правильно спроектировать класс, чтобы можно было при необходимости (если таковая имеется) из другого места изменить его внутренние данные.

В общем, извращение, конечно.

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, можно сделать static-функцию-член класса и передавать указатель на нее. Только ведь принципиально эта ф-ция ничем  от "свободной" ф-ции отличаться не будет.

Comment: Это известная вещь и неинтересная. Мой вариант позволяет в определенном случае вызывать именно функцию-член, которая имеет доступ к нестатическим элементам объекта. А статическая функция такового не имеет, естественно.

Comment: Почему? В данном случае мы ограничены тем, что мы не можем передать `*this` внутрь ф-ции, т.к. ее сигнатура жестко задана. Но нам никто не мешает создать static-член класса, который сохранит ссылку на экземпляр класса. На [SO][1] такая методика и применяется. Но насколько я понимаю косяк заключается в том, что получается объект, который можно создать один раз... Вторая копия будет уже работать некорректно...

 [1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3589422/using-opengl-glutdisplayfunc-within-class

Comment: Ну, в общем решение близко к моему. Хотя и потенциально опасное.

Comment: Какие минусы оно имеет? Мне не нравится, что в Вашем варианте все размазывается по global namespace. В случае со статической ф-цией-членом класса вся механика остается внутри... Иначе смысла с ООП в данном случае заморачиваться нет, ИМХО.

Comment: Ну, решение конечно дерьмо, я об этом уже писал.

Comment: На SO народ договорился до того, что нужно callback ф-цию объявлять как extern "C" для обеспечения совместимости ABI.

Answer (score 0):

При работе с OpenGl и C++ важно понять, что OpenGl писался не на C++ а на C коде. Так же поддерживаются и другие языки. Библиотеки построены таким образом, что вызов функции идет через **cdecl и тут кроме объявления static - ничего не поможет.... НО!!! есть одна очень результативная хитрость!!! C++ сам по себе так же и процедурный язык программирования, а для процедур - не нужно указывать static (при** cdecl), а соответственно можно использовать динамические адреса, массивы адресов и т.п. А если написать свой конвейер на реализации вызовов процедур от других классов? Ну то есть одна глобальная функция реализующая обработку объектов класса по их адресам? Да долго, да не сразу все строится, но ведь и OpenGl не сразу написано было... Написав её один раз, можно применять уже для любого класса... И вперед... Как кто думает? Я тоже ищу варианты - пока пробую сделать так - вроде работает (а куда денется)))). А перенаправлять адреса и мудрить с ними по другому - все это упрется в объявлении одной функции для всех и нет того результата. И есть ли вариант проще?

Answer (score -1):

Допустим сделал я такой изврат.

```
int *ptr=NULL;
void (A::*_a)(void);
_a = &A::say;
_ptr= (int*) &_a;
glutDisplayFunc((void(*)()) ( (int) *_ptr));
```

А теперь как достучатся до членов класса, они не доступны из за того что callback функция работает в отдельном потоке?

```
void A:say()
{
    cout << "I say: " << i << endl;  //всё упало,  здесь 77 ну никак получается
}
```